# Error- When importing .sql file in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a **.sql** file which is created with **[MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)**.I have done Export file from **Workbench** to **.sql**.But when i try to import this **.sql** file in ***localhost/phpmyadmin*** its showing an error.

> 1005 - Can't create table `amarjobs`.`profiles` (errno: 150 "Foreign
>   key constraint is incorrectly formed")

This is `profiles` table:

```
-- Table `amarjobs`.`profiles`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `amarjobs`.`profiles` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'job seeker\'s profile table',
  `userID` INT NULL,
  `firstName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `lastName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `middleName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `DOB` DATE NULL,
  `gender` ENUM('M','F','Other') NULL,
  `featuredProfile` ENUM('Y','N') NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `summary` VARCHAR(500) NULL,
  `profilePic` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fkProfilesUserID_idx` (`userID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fkProfilesUserID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userID`)
    REFERENCES `amarjobs`.`users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Some table was imported but why `profiles` table is not imported? Could you tell me where is the problem?

Comment: check Foreign key and referenced primary key column type it should be same

Comment: Please take a look `users` table and `profiles` table in http://pastebin.com/asPW444K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are importing data from some other server. so there should not be issues related with foreign key creation...

First import its parent table `users` table then you can import this table. This is the clean way.

Other wise you can forcefully import after setting foreign_key_checks disable. But you should not do it and use clean way.

**Update:**

You can get all related tables by this query:

```
SELECT table_name AS 'My_Table',REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME AS 'Parent_Table' FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='pass_your_db_here' AND table_name in ('table1','table2',.....'tablen') AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL;
```

above query will provide all parents tables for your all tables in parent_table columnd so get unique tables from my_table & parent_table list and take backup of these tables from source server and restore on target server.

Comment: If i do in your way then `profiles` table is imported but another table `profile_skills` is showing same error.I want to know actually what is the problem?

Comment: how you took backup...you should take backup by mysqldump utility and then import by mysql utility.....actually when you will create any child table then first it will check its reference/parent table so normally first you need to create parent table then you can import child table...

Comment: for a trick you can do : open your backup file (.sql) in any editor as per your platform window/linux and add a line "set foreign_key_checks=0;" in the begginning and "set foreign_key_checks=1;" at the end...it will import all your tables......but if any parent table is missing in your db then constraint will not work properly...

Comment: it have already `set foreign_key_checks=0` .I think **''but if any parent table is missing in your db then constraint will not work properly''** this is the main problem but dont know where to solve?

Comment: first of all you should aware which table should go to target server if you are taking partial db backup...further you can follow steps as I mentioned in my update.

Comment: I was doing another way.But your answer help me to find out the solution.Now i mark your answer.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should make (id) a primary key in `amarjobs`.`users` table.